# How to find a value to make function positive and real?

Tags: equation-solving, random

Let

```
x=(((-3 + r) r^2 + a^2 (1 + r)) Csc[θ])/(a (-1 + r))

y=Sqrt[(a^2 (a^2 (1 + r)^2 + 2 r^2 (-3 + r^2)) + 
 a^4 (-1 + r)^2 Cos[θ]^2 - ((-3 + r) r^2 + 
    a^2 (1 + r))^2 Csc[θ]^2)/(a^2 (-1 + r)^2)]
```

where $0<a<1$, $0<\theta\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

I am looking for a two values of $r$ where (1) both $x$ and $y$ are real and (2) both $x$ and $y$ are real and positive.

If we choose some value for $a$ and $\theta$, is there a way to find the two values of $r$ without solving the $x$ or $y$?

Thanks.

Comment: You try Solve? Or NDSolve?

Comment: You can just use `FindInstance[]`?

Comment: `fi[a_, \[Theta]_] :=  
  FindInstance[
   x[a, \[Theta]] > 0 && y[a, \[Theta]] > 0 && 
    x[a, \[Theta]] \[Element] Reals && 
    y[a, \[Theta]] \[Element] Reals, r, 2]`,`fi[0.5, 0.5]` will just give you two values which satisfy (2), and therefore also (1).

Comment: @Feyre If you specify that `sth > 0` it automatically is also `Real`; `\[Element] Reals` is unnecesary.

Answer (score 2):

The following, based on Freye's comment, will allow you to explore the solution space.

```
finder[a_, θ_] :=
  Block[{x, y, r},
    x[aa_, theta_] := ((-3 + r) r^2 + aa^2 (1 + r)) Csc[theta]/(aa (-1 + r));
    y[aa_, theta_] := 
      Sqrt[
        (aa^2 (aa^2 (1 + r)^2 + 2 r^2 (-3 + r^2)) + 
           aa^4 (-1 + r)^2 Cos[theta]^2 - 
           ((-3 + r) r^2 + aa^2 (1 + r))^2 Csc[theta]^2) /
        (aa^2 (-1 + r)^2)];
    Module[{sols},
      sols = FindInstance[x[a, θ] > 0 && y[a, θ] > 0, r, 2];
      {r, x[a, θ], y[a, θ]} /. sols]]

Manipulate[
  Column[
    Row[{"r = ", #[[1]], "; x = ", #[[2]], "; y = ", #[[3]]}] & /@ finder[a, θ]],
  {{a, .5}, .01, 1., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{θ, .5}, .01, π/2., Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]